# Problem running roscore on macosx10.6

Tags: python, roslaunch, macos-snowleopard, roscore, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i am having issue when running roscore.

The error is :

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/bin/roscore", line 34, in 
from ros import roslaunch
File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/ros/**init**.py", line 57, in **getattr**
return **import**(name)
File "/opt/ros/electric/ros_comm/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/**init**.py", line 53, in 
from roslaunch.scriptapi import ROSLaunch
File "/opt/ros/electric/ros_comm/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/scriptapi.py", line 42, in 
import roslaunch.parent
File "/opt/ros/electric/ros_comm/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/parent.py", line 55, in 
import roslaunch.server
File "/opt/ros/electric/ros_comm/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/server.py", line 70, in 
from rosgraph_msgs.msg import Log
ImportError: No module named rosgraph_msgs.msg

I have try to install python using the following command:
sudo easy_install python-yaml

The export | grep ros is :

declare -x PATH="/opt/ros/electric/ros/bin:/opt/ros/electric/ros/bin:/opt/ros/electric/ros/bin:/opt/ros/electric/ros/bin:/opt/ros/electric/ros/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin"
declare -x PYTHONPATH="/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src:/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src:/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src:/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src:/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src:"
declare -x ROS_PACKAGE_PATH="/opt/ros/electric/robot_model_tutorials:/opt/ros/electric/visualization_tutorials:/opt/ros/electric/geometry_tutorials:/opt/ros/electric/common_tutorials:/opt/ros/electric/ros_tutorials:/opt/ros/electric/documentation:/opt/ros/electric/geometry_experimental:/opt/ros/electric/robot_model_visualization:/opt/ros/electric/geometry_visualization:/opt/ros/electric/diagnostics_monitors:/opt/ros/electric/executive_smach_visualization:/opt/ros/electric/visualization:/opt/ros/electric/slam_gmapping:/opt/ros/electric/navigation:/opt/ros/electric/vision_opencv:/opt/ros/electric/laser_pipeline:/opt/ros/electric/image_pipeline:/opt/ros/electric/image_transport_plugins:/opt/ros/electric/perception_pcl:/opt/ros/electric/image_common:/opt/ros/electric/rx:/opt/ros/electric/visualization_common:/opt/ros/electric/physics_ode:/opt/ros/electric/stage:/opt/ros/electric/simulator_gazebo:/opt/ros/electric/simulator_stage:/opt/ros/electric/xacro:/opt/ros/electric/executive_smach:/opt/ros/electric/robot_model:/opt/ros/electric/assimp:/opt/ros/electric/pluginlib:/opt/ros/electric/orocos_kinematics_dynamics:/opt/ros/electric/nodelet_core:/opt/ros/electric/geometry:/opt/ros/electric/bullet:/opt/ros/electric/filters:/opt/ros/electric/eigen:/opt/ros/electric/driver_common:/opt/ros/electric/diagnostics:/opt/ros/electric/common:/opt/ros/electric/common_msgs:/opt/ros/electric/bond_core:/opt/ros/electric/common_rosdeps:/opt/ros/electric/ros_comm:/opt/ros/electric/ros"
declare -x ROS_ROOT="/opt/ros/electric/ros"
declare -x ROS_WORKSPACE="/opt/ros/electric"

Please advise. Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34418/problem-running-roscore-on-macosx10.6/) by [halfstopper](https://answers.ros.org/users/2417/halfstopper/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2012-05-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2012-05-21**:
Can you post the output of `export | grep ROS`?  What version of Xcode are you using? Which installation instructions did you use?

**Comment by [halfstopper](https://answers.ros.org/users/2417/halfstopper/) on 2012-05-21**:
The Xcode version I am using is 3.2.6. I installing ros electric from the link : http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/OSX/Homebrew

I install ros to /opt/ros/electric path
I am new to installing to mac.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The important line from this error is:

```
"/opt/ros/electric/ros_comm/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/server.py", line 70, in <module> from rosgraph_msgs.msg import Log ImportError: No module named rosgraph_msgs.msg
```

This means it cannot find the msg module in the rosgraph_msg pkg or it cannot find the rosgraph_msg pkg.

It could be that your environment was not setup correctly, but looking at your feedback to my comment above that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Additionally, it could be that rosgraph_msgs is not built, try running `rosmake rosgraph_msgs` and then try using roslaunch again.  If rosgraph_msgs wasn't built you might have had other issues, make sure you can run `rosmake ros ros_comm` without failure.  This will ensure that everything has been built and generated successfully.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2012-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1